# component does not support consuming from this endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

When I mock an asynchronous endpoint, I receive the above error

Have tried creating the mock for a direct endpoint with Processor argument.
from("direct:http://localhost:7001/").process(new Processor() {...}

```
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("ahc:http://localhost:7001/").process(new AsyncProcessor() {
                        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange,Exchange.class);
                        }
                        public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback) {
                            if(exchange.hasOut()) {
                                exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange,Exchange.class);
                                callback.done(true);
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Camel Async Http Client](https://camel.apache.org/ahc.html) is an **HTTP client** component.

Therefore **you cannot use it in a `.from(...)` endpoint** because this would create an HTTP listener, i.e. an HTTP server that waits for requests.

What you can do with it, is making HTTP requests.

```
.from(whatever)
.to("ahc:http://localhost:7001/")
```

will - when triggered - make a request to `http://localhost:7001` and save the HTTP response in the Exchange body.

Comment: Can you provide an example in terms of Camel Mock Test which uses ahc component?